# divide by zero encountered in log scipy.stats.boxcox

Tags: python, scipy

I'm encountering really strange reproducible behaviour for the [`boxcox`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html#scipy-stats-boxcox) function of `scipy` that I cannot quite explain.

Apologies for the long example but it seems to be specifically **this** data that causes the issue:

```
data = [1710, 1262, 1786, 1717, 2198, 1362, 1694, 2090, 1774, 1077, 1040, 2324, 912, 1494, 1253, 854, 1004, 1296, 1114, 1339, 2376, 1108, 1795, 1060, 1060, 1600, 900, 1704, 1600, 520, 1317, 1228, 1234, 1700, 1561, 2452, 1097, 1297, 1057, 1152, 1324, 1328, 884, 938, 1150, 1752, 2149, 1656, 1452, 955, 1470, 1176, 816, 1842, 1360, 1425, 1739, 1720, 2945, 780, 1158, 1111, 1370, 1710, 2034, 2473, 2207, 1479, 747, 2287, 2223, 845, 1718, 1086, 1605, 988, 952, 1285, 1768, 1230, 2142, 1337, 1563, 1065, 1474, 2417, 1560, 1224, 1526, 990, 1040, 1235, 964, 2291, 1786, 1470, 1588, 960, 835, 1225, 1610, 1732, 1535, 1226, 1818, 1992, 1047, 789, 1517, 1844, 1855, 1430, 2696, 2259, 2320, 1458, 1092, 1125, 3222, 1456, 988, 1123, 1080, 1199, 1586, 754, 958, 840, 1348, 1053, 2157, 2054, 1327, 1296, 1721, 1682, 1214, 1959, 1852, 1764, 864, 1734, 1385, 1501, 1728, 1709, 875, 2035, 1080, 1344, 969, 1710, 1993, 1252, 1200, 1096, 1040, 1968, 1947, 2462, 1232, 2668, 1541, 882, 1616, 1355, 1867, 2161, 1720, 1707, 1382, 1656, 1767, 1362, 1651, 2158, 2060, 1920, 2234, 968, 1525, 1802, 1340, 2082, 1252, 3608, 1217, 1656, 1224, 1593, 2727, 1479, 1431, 1709, 864, 1456, 1726, 3112, 2229, 1713, 1121, 1279, 1310, 848, 1284, 1442, 1696, 1100, 2062, 1092, 864, 1212, 1852, 990, 1392, 1236, 1436, 1328, 1954, 1248, 1498, 2267, 1552, 864, 2392, 1302, 2520, 987, 912, 1555, 1194, 2794, 987, 894, 1960, 987, 1414, 1744, 1694, 1487, 1566, 866, 1440, 1217, 2110, 1872, 1928, 1375, 1668, 2144, 1306, 1625, 1640, 1302, 1314, 2291, 1728, 1604, 1792, 882, 1382, 2574, 1212, 1316, 764, 1422, 1511, 2192, 778, 1113, 1939, 1363, 2270, 1632, 816, 1548, 1560, 864, 2121, 2022, 1982, 1262, 1314, 1468, 1575, 1250, 1734, 858, 900, 1396, 1919, 1716, 1716, 2263, 1644, 1003, 1558, 1950, 1743, 1152, 1336, 2452, 1541, 894, 3493, 2000, 2243, 1406, 861, 1944, 1501, 972, 1118, 2036, 1641, 1432, 2353, 1959, 2646, 1472, 2596, 2468, 2730, 1163, 2978, 803, 1719, 1383, 2134, 1192, 1728, 1056, 1629, 1358, 1638, 1786, 1922, 1536, 1621, 1215, 1908, 841, 1040, 1684, 1112, 1577, 958, 1478, 1626, 2728, 1869, 1453, 1111, 720, 1595, 1200, 1167, 1142, 1352, 1924, 912, 1505, 1922, 987, 1574, 1344, 1394, 1431, 1268, 1287, 1664, 1588, 752, 1319, 1928, 904, 914, 2466, 1856, 1800, 1691, 1301, 1797, 784, 1953, 1269, 1184, 1125, 1479, 2332, 1367, 1961, 882, 788, 1034, 1144, 894, 1812, 1077, 1550, 1288, 1310, 672, 2263, 1572, 1620, 1639, 1680, 2172, 2078, 1276, 1056, 1478, 1028, 2097, 1340, 1400, 2624, 1134, 1056, 1344, 1602, 988, 2630, 1196, 1389, 1644, 907, 1208, 1412, 987, 1198, 1365, 1604, 630, 1661, 1118, 904, 694, 1196, 2402, 1440, 1573, 1258, 1908, 1689, 1888, 1886, 1376, 1183, 813, 1533, 1756, 1590, 1728, 1242, 1344, 1663, 1666, 1203, 1935, 1135, 864, 1660, 1040, 1414, 1277, 1644, 1634, 1710, 1502, 1969, 1072, 1976, 1652, 970, 1493, 2643, 1718, 1131, 1850, 1792, 1826, 1216, 999, 1113, 1073, 1484, 2414, 630, 1304, 1578, 1456, 1269, 886, 720, 3228, 1820, 899, 912, 1218, 1768, 1214, 1801, 1322, 1960, 1911, 1218, 1378, 1041, 1363, 1368, 864, 1080, 789, 2020, 2119, 2344, 1796, 2080, 1294, 1244, 1664, 4676, 2398, 1266, 928, 2713, 605, 2515, 1509, 1362, 827, 334, 1414, 1347, 1724, 864, 1159, 1601, 1838, 2285, 1680, 767, 1496, 2183, 1635, 768, 825, 2094, 1069, 928, 1717, 1126, 2046, 1048, 1092, 1336, 1446, 1557, 1392, 1389, 996, 1674, 2295, 1647, 2504, 1535, 2132, 943, 1728, 864, 1692, 1430, 1109, 1216, 1477, 1320, 1392, 1795, 1429, 2042, 816, 2775, 1573, 2028, 838, 860, 1473, 935, 1582, 2296, 816, 848, 924, 1826, 1368, 1402, 1647, 1556, 1904, 1375, 1915, 1200, 1494, 1986, 1040, 2008, 3194, 1029, 2153, 1032, 1872, 1120, 630, 1054, 1509, 832, 1828, 2262, 864, 2614, 980, 1512, 1790, 1116, 1422, 1520, 2080, 1350, 1750, 1554, 1411, 1056, 1056, 3395, 800, 1387, 796, 1567, 1518, 1929, 2704, 1620, 1766, 981, 1048, 1094, 1839, 630, 1665, 1510, 1716, 1469, 2113, 1092, 1053, 1502, 1458, 1486, 1935, 2448, 1392, 1181, 2097, 1936, 2380, 1679, 1437, 1180, 1476, 1369, 1208, 1839, 1136, 1441, 1774, 792, 2046, 988, 923, 1520, 1291, 1668, 1839, 2090, 1761, 1102, 1419, 1362, 848, 4316, 2519, 1073, 1539, 1137, 616, 1148, 894, 1391, 1800, 1164, 2576, 1812, 1484, 1092, 1824, 1324, 1456, 904, 729, 1178, 1228, 960, 1479, 1350, 2554, 1178, 2418, 971, 1742, 848, 864, 1470, 1698, 864, 1680, 1232, 1776, 1208, 1616, 1146, 2031, 1144, 948, 1768, 1040, 1801, 1200, 1728, 1432, 912, 1349, 1464, 1337, 2715, 2256, 2640, 1720, 1529, 1140, 1320, 1494, 2098, 1026, 1471, 1768, 1386, 1501, 2531, 864, 1301, 1547, 2365, 1494, 1506, 1714, 1750, 1836, 3279, 858, 1220, 1117, 912, 1973, 1204, 1614, 894, 2020, 1004, 1253, 1603, 1430, 1110, 1484, 1342, 1652, 2084, 901, 2087, 1145, 1062, 2013, 1496, 1895, 1564, 1285, 773, 3140, 1768, 1688, 1196, 1456, 2822, 1128, 1428, 980, 1576, 1086, 2138, 1309, 848, 1044, 1442, 1250, 1661, 1008, 1689, 1052, 1358, 1640, 936, 1733, 1489, 1489, 2084, 784, 1434, 2126, 1223, 1392, 1200, 1829, 1516, 1144, 1067, 1559, 987, 1099, 1200, 1482, 1539, 1165, 1800, 1416, 1701, 1775, 864, 2358, 1855, 848, 1456, 1646, 1445, 1779, 1040, 1026, 1481, 1370, 2654, 1426, 1039, 1097, 1148, 1372, 1002, 1646, 1120, 2320, 1949, 894, 1682, 910, 1268, 1131, 2610, 1040, 2224, 1155, 864, 1090, 1717, 1593, 2230, 892, 1709, 1712, 1393, 2217, 1505, 924, 1683, 1068, 1383, 1535, 1796, 951, 2240, 2364, 1236, 858, 1306, 1509, 1670, 902, 1063, 1636, 2057, 902, 1484, 2274, 1268, 1015, 2002, 1224, 1092, 480, 1229, 2127, 1414, 1721, 2200, 1316, 1617, 1686, 1126, 2374, 1978, 1788, 2236, 1466, 925, 1905, 1500, 2069, 747, 1200, 1971, 1962, 2403, 1728, 2060, 1440, 1632, 1344, 1869, 1144, 1629, 1776, 1381, 864, 965, 768, 1968,
980, 1958, 1229, 1057, 1337, 1416, 858, 2872, 1548, 1800, 1894, 1484, 1308, 1098, 968, 1095, 1192, 1626, 918, 1428, 2019, 1382, 869, 1241, 894, 1121, 999, 2612, 1266, 2290, 1734, 1164, 1635, 1940, 2030, 1576, 2392, 1742, 1851, 1500, 1718, 1230, 1050, 1442, 1077, 1208, 944, 691, 1574, 1680, 1504, 985, 1657, 1092, 1710, 1522, 1271, 1664, 1502, 1022, 1082, 1665, 1504, 1360, 1472, 1506, 1132, 1220, 1248, 1504, 2898, 882, 1264, 1646, 1376, 1218, 1928, 3082, 2520, 1654, 954, 845, 1620, 2263, 1344, 630, 1803, 1632, 1306, 2329, 2524, 1733, 2868, 990, 1771, 930, 1302, 1316, 1977, 1526, 1989, 1523, 1364, 1850, 2184, 1991, 1338, 894, 2337, 1103, 1154, 2260, 1571, 1611, 2521, 893, 1048, 1556, 1456, 1426, 1240, 1740, 1466, 1096, 848, 990, 1258, 1040, 1459, 1251, 1498, 996, 1092, 1953, 1709, 1247, 1040, 1252, 1694, 1200, 936, 1314, 1355, 1088, 1324, 1601, 438, 950, 1134, 1194, 1302, 2622, 1442, 2021, 1690, 1836, 1658, 1964, 816, 1008, 833, 1734, 1419, 894, 1601, 1040, 1012, 1552, 960, 698, 1482, 1005, 1555, 1530, 1959, 936, 1981, 974, 2210, 2020, 1600, 986, 1252, 1020, 1567, 1167, 952, 1868, 2828, 1006, 924, 1576, 1298, 1564, 1111, 1482, 932, 1466, 1811, 816, 1820, 1437, 1265, 1314, 1580, 1876, 1456, 1640, 894, 1258, 1432, 1502, 1694, 1671, 2108, 3627, 1118, 1261, 1250, 3086, 2345, 2872, 923, 1224, 1343, 1124, 2514, 1652, 4476, 1130, 1572, 1221, 1699, 1624, 1660, 1804, 1622, 1441, 1472, 1224, 1352, 1456, 1863, 1690, 1212, 1382, 864, 1779, 1348, 1630, 1074, 2196, 1056, 1700, 1283, 1660, 1845, 1752, 672, 960, 999, 894, 1902, 1314, 912, 1218, 912, 1211, 1846, 2136, 1490, 1138, 1933, 912, 1702, 1507, 2620, 1190, 1224, 1188, 1964, 1784, 1626, 1948, 1141, 1484, 1768, 1689, 1173, 2076, 1517, 1868, 1553, 1034, 2058, 988, 2110, 1405, 874, 2167, 1656, 1367, 1987, 864, 1166, 1054, 1675, 1050, 1788, 1824, 1337, 1452, 1889, 2018, 3447, 1524, 1524, 1489, 935, 1357, 1250, 1920, 1395, 1724, 2031, 1128, 1573, 1339, 1040, 1824, 2447, 1412, 1328, 1582, 1659, 1970, 1152, 1302, 2372, 1664, 864, 1052, 1128, 1072, 5642, 1246, 1983, 1494, 2526, 1616, 1708, 1652, 1368, 990, 1122, 1294, 1902, 1274, 2810, 2599, 948, 2112, 1630, 1352, 1787, 948, 1478, 720, 1923, 708, 1795, 796, 774, 816, 2792, 1632, 1588, 954, 816, 1360, 1365, 1334, 1656, 693, 1861, 864, 872, 1114, 2169, 1913, 1456, 960, 2156, 1776, 1494, 2358, 2634, 1716, 1176, 3238, 1865, 1920, 892, 1078, 1573, 1980, 2601, 1530, 1738, 1412, 1200, 1674, 1790, 1475, 848, 1668, 1374, 1661, 2097, 2633, 1958, 1571, 790, 1604, 987, 1394, 864, 2117, 1762, 1416, 1258, 1154, 2784, 2526, 1746, 1218, 1525, 1584, 900, 1912, 1500, 2482, 1687, 1513, 1904, 1608, 1158, 1593, 1294, 1464, 1214, 1646, 768, 833, 1363, 2093, 1840, 1668, 1040, 1844, 1848, 1569, 2290, 2450, 1144, 1844, 1416, 1069, 848, 2201, 1344, 1252, 2127, 1558, 804, 1440, 1838, 958, 968, 1792, 1126, 1537, 864, 1932, 1236, 1725, 2555, 848, 2007, 952, 1422, 913, 1188, 2090, 1346, 630, 1792, 1578, 1072, 1140, 1221, 1647, 2073, 2340, 1078, 1256, 896, 1329, 1629, 1604, 1280, 1655, 1187, 1465, 1341, 882, 1337, 987, 1092, 1456, 836, 2334, 1544, 1698, 1822, 2696, 2250, 1370, 1324, 1145, 1374, 1733, 2475, 1595, 1218, 1468, 1659, 1012, 1494, 2349, 2225, 1488, 1680, 1200, 1200, 1236, 1512, 1080, 1418, 1848, 1492, 1829, 2495, 1891, 1645, 1232, 1209, 1510, 1775, 1728, 2461, 1556, 1128, 1604, 1480, 1143, 1206, 1580, 1337, 1064, 972, 988, 985, 1224, 1175, 1395, 1844, 936, 1347, 1251, 1633, 1245, 832, 1566, 2268, 2256, 1470, 1612, 2068, 765, 1132, 1196, 1453, 1416, 1040, 1536, 1068, 1962, 1560, 1324, 1675, 1224, 1392, 919, 1884, 1680, 1832, 892, 864, 1373, 1440, 1483, 756, 1981, 1610, 1074, 1531, 1172, 1508, 1298, 1433, 1802, 1222, 1445, 965, 1692, 1026, 876, 1978, 2098, 848, 640, 992, 1196, 1120, 1096, 960, 1296, 856, 2650, 1666, 2133, 2177, 1652, 1034, 1191, 540, 1107, 952, 1646, 1916, 1285, 2048, 1346, 1214, 1444, 1264, 1430, 1344, 945, 1092, 1092, 1092, 874, 833, 2432, 1274, 1479, 1803, 1797, 882, 1434, 1608, 2283, 1628, 2522, 1478, 1734, 1382, 1636, 1516, 1190, 1934, 2050, 1671, 2673, 1707, 1884, 1874, 1811, 1621, 1116, 1193, 1180, 1050, 864, 864, 987, 987, 1548, 1055, 1456, 1548, 1456, 836, 1120, 2772, 2690, 2020, 2674, 1736, 1782, 2520, 1743, 1531, 1808, 1760, 2452, 2400, 1606, 1358, 1306, 1358, 2492, 2200, 1884, 1456, 1712, 1405, 1456, 1490, 1220, 1374, 1630, 1594, 1489, 1342, 2004, 1374, 1514, 1430, 2312, 1430, 2687, 2063, 2061, 2232, 1696, 1658, 1702, 1432, 2490, 1436, 1402, 1530, 1448, 1795, 1836, 1662, 1553, 1653, 1218, 1141, 1158, 1812, 1512, 1114, 1114, 1114, 1450, 2122, 1730, 1332, 1540, 1400, 1882, 980, 864, 864, 1020, 912, 912, 2014, 1755, 3005, 1726, 1256, 1512, 1452, 1694, 1740, 2499, 2067, 2640, 1336, 1216, 2288, 864, 1568, 2061, 1320, 894, 864, 1362, 1728, 1313, 1292, 2140, 1576, 960, 1691, 1453, 1567, 1144, 1329, 988, 1202, 1382, 1200, 1866, 1062, 1112, 793, 1031, 1210, 1527, 1200, 792, 1352, 1039, 1078, 2377, 1690, 599, 846, 725, 2544, 1380, 1040, 951, 1105, 1142, 1133, 1041, 732, 1183, 1461, 1495, 1806, 941, 1045, 1378, 1944, 1306, 1464, 1558, 1701, 1447, 1328, 861, 612, 792, 1510, 2007, 1288, 816, 1480, 1521, 797, 1432, 1654, 1142, 995, 1582, 1072, 1768, 1944, 2128, 1930, 1427, 1864, 1666, 892, 1403, 704, 1200, 1152, 1112, 1052, 1034, 1774, 1138, 2071, 660, 1383, 1073, 1639, 1089, 1049, 1061, 1338, 1879, 2016, 2228, 1535, 1229, 1513, 2787, 2787, 2787, 1680, 1720, 1468, 1838, 1290, 1254, 1498, 1422, 1759, 990, 1463, 1772, 1444, 1492, 907, 914, 1611, 2184, 1725, 1870, 1513, 1828, 1417, 1602, 1396, 1149, 1072, 876, 1368, 1678, 1560, 1298, 1268, 1242, 1232, 1228, 1567, 1273, 2480, 1112, 1561, 1523, 1906, 1032, 1229, 1229, 1982, 2365, 2168, 572, 1648, 810, 2052, 926, 1287, 1595, 2036, 1641, 2237, 1479, 2014, 1978, 1008, 1404, 796, 1091, 883, 1287, 1632, 1604, 1470, 1604, 1636, 1384, 1682, 1280, 1633, 1709, 1337, 2500, 1884, 1474, 1710, 1488, 1688, 1260, 2064, 1782, 1211, 2044, 1308, 2840, 1444, 2340, 1792, 936, 864, 987, 987, 1302, 1456, 1055, 1582, 2464, 1950, 2748, 2790, 2331, 2088, 2332, 2470, 1575, 2649, 2690, 1866, 1367, 1800, 1342, 1342, 1626, 1455, 1576, 1246, 1515, 1720, 1986, 1358, 1892, 1414, 2322, 1651, 2199, 2172, 2006, 2125, 2501, 2197, 1578, 1861, 1874, 1460, 1372, 1660, 1218, 1696, 1663, 1175, 1162, 1609, 1680, 1657, 1677, 1737, 984, 864, 890, 864, 1430, 1641, 2683, 2786, 1245, 1200, 1392, 1549, 1638, 1310, 1419, 1557, 1404, 1789, 1586, 1607, 2393, 1239, 2944, 1671, 1812, 1427, 1740, 1620, 1625, 1464, 925, 1728, 1670, 1014, 1114, 1118, 906, 1496, 1337, 1036, 1988, 1176, 1440, 1570, 1104, 882, 1152, 950, 1790, 1764, 1824, 869, 1159, 672, 1436, 1044, 1312, 1081, 876, 1256, 1027, 1320, 984, 1278, 1800, 1588, 825, 1117, 1133, 1323, 1360, 672, 1456, 1594, 1656, 1740, 1027, 1436, 899, 1080, 1499, 407, 1588, 1627, 1450, 1017, 2350, 1540, 1086, 2495, 984, 1093, 1143, 1668, 1738, 1210, 1290, 1672, 949, 1497, 1342, 1013, 1216, 896, 1136, 808, 2009, 1902, 1716, 1984, 1609, 768, 1536, 1969, 1308, 1040, 1236, 759, 1344, 1054, 1075, 1096, 992, 1034, 1073, 1126, 1140, 960, 1188, 1721, 1350, 904, 1524, 1079, 1518, 1509, 864, 1269, 2814, 1626, 2200, 2037, 1356, 1615, 2276, 1766, 1511, 1643, 990, 1418, 1771, 1652, 1823, 1174, 1076, 1558, 2161, 1947, 1786, 2327, 1764, 848, 1838, 1445, 1564, 1361, 1092, 1033, 1127, 1117, 1398, 3820, 1152, 1152, 784, 1053, 1137, 930, 1204, 1292, 1424, 1920, 1316, 1264, 1512, 1603, 1938, 1374, 1091, 1873, 2161, 1898, 1032, 919, 1090, 1200, 1656, 912, 1955, 733, 1361, 1049, 864, 1648, 1646, 2032, 1820, 1872, 1689, 1501, 1537, 1780, 1442, 1612, 1495, 1256, 1440, 1675, 1728, 1964, 1344, 1092, 1189, 1200, 1040, 1475, 988, 988, 1160, 1092, 816, 845, 889, 1836, 1587, 1384, 1694, 1714, 1553, 2299, 1187, 1642, 1128, 1179, 1321, 2541, 2338, 1424, 1612, 2234, 2042, 1284, 1479, 1664, 1930, 1177, 1353, 1220, 1324, 1877, 1422, 914, 914, 1337, 1337, 1092, 1218, 1055, 988, 1816, 1694, 2122, 2656, 2550, 2046, 2552, 2758, 2290, 2152, 2100, 1802, 2956, 2385, 1818, 1614, 1721, 1828, 1302, 1302, 1362, 1554, 1577, 1324, 1405, 1496, 1536, 1458, 1495, 1746, 1326, 1504, 1456, 1258, 1589, 1266, 1119, 1374, 1525, 1394, 1948, 1995, 1690, 1644, 2551, 3078, 2582, 2385, 2202, 2538, 1369, 1542, 1534, 1966, 1528, 1538, 1506, 1977, 1830, 1338, 1335, 1792, 1588, 1880, 1584, 1685, 2443, 1100, 1143, 1094, 1486, 1820, 1266, 894, 1040, 2503, 1037, 1055, 1378, 1151, 1565, 1352, 1550, 1501, 1573, 1358, 2048, 2362, 1494, 2362, 2497, 1152, 2411, 1082, 1295, 1610, 1594, 2075, 1093, 1052, 1107, 1224, 1074, 1187, 964, 894, 1200, 1042, 2154, 1374, 1652, 908, 666, 670, 808, 1150, 1560, 1280, 1254, 936, 1008, 1053, 1144, 1721, 922, 1411, 1216, 1154, 1560, 948, 1040, 925, 1540, 925, 1647, 924, 1544, 1728, 3086, 1281, 1534, 1651, 888, 952, 1238, 1040, 1170, 1242, 1377, 925, 864, 936, 960, 1296, 1022, 967, 1072, 1174, 1141, 1798, 1772, 1642, 1232, 1650, 1358, 2454, 968, 1382, 1060, 1435, 1274, 1232, 884, 1409, 1322, 1426, 1281, 2264, 1376, 1316, 1344, 1173, 1214, 2294, 1952, 2180, 1315, 1484, 2267, 1282, 999, 1452, 1005, 1020, 1040, 868, 897, 943, 912, 1375, 2654, 1302, 1299, 1176, 998, 1522, 1325, 1630, 1242, 2422, 1626, 864, 943, 1038, 1342, 1480, 1362, 1822, 1958, 1651, 2140, 1651, 1546, 1500, 1270, 1795, 1873, 1743, 1022, 1308, 990, 1097, 1873, 1753, 1690, 1842, 894, 1025, 1009, 1040, 907, 879, 864, 875, 1673, 1932, 1729, 1592, 2439, 1992, 1341, 1476, 1190, 1330, 1491, 1536, 936, 1088, 1351, 1179, 1044, 2233, 1408, 5095, 1072, 960, 1152, 1195, 865, 768, 864, 2592, 1422, 1298, 1098, 1436, 1461, 1718, 1226, 1755, 1355, 1560, 1488, 1045, 1680, 1020, 1696, 2726, 1215, 1601, 1828, 816, 845, 1991, 1073, 1001, 1625, 1299, 1392, 1409, 1478, 918, 1026, 1501, 2279, 1689, 1564, 1240, 1312, 1922, 1491, 2486, 1824, 2034, 936, 1092, 992, 1092, 1092, 1008, 1356, 1676, 1432, 796, 1608, 1178, 816, 887, 1293, 1024, 1797, 1390, 1851, 1525, 1671, 1776, 2064, 2212, 2687, 1169, 1204, 2798, 3390, 2473, 2698, 2795, 1714, 2000, 1102, 1857, 1083, 2318, 1875, 1103, 874, 1419, 1092, 1365, 1030, 948, 1092, 1069, 1387, 1055, 1456, 2589, 1618, 1740, 1868, 2206, 2091, 2253, 2389, 2358, 1792, 1780, 1914, 1565, 1686, 1666, 1456, 1492, 1326, 2373, 1492, 1364, 1511, 1548, 1142, 1598, 1889, 2322, 1976, 2234, 2855, 2726, 3500, 2494, 2799, 1964, 1670, 1504, 1278, 2640, 1716, 1142, 1400, 1131, 1686, 1585, 1837, 1731, 1398, 1217, 1320, 988, 1654, 1211, 984, 909, 925, 1024, 912, 941, 2646, 2826, 1143, 1223, 1524, 1080, 1694, 1568, 1193, 1334, 1051, 1770, 976, 898, 1051, 1141, 1565, 1488, 1440, 1248, 816, 1043, 1433, 1624, 1216, 1728, 936, 1584, 1246, 1008, 1364, 1336, 1370, 1124, 1050, 1008, 1575, 1145, 1005, 1056, 884, 2039, 1384, 2640, 1312, 713, 715, 720, 1595, 1760, 1146, 1207, 1773, 1472, 2448, 1521, 1040, 1556, 1150, 1045, 864, 1025, 2014, 1668, 1657, 1416, 1428, 1004, 1951, 1032, 844, 864, 1376, 960, 1566, 492, 1182, 840, 2104, 1248, 960, 1020, 1827, 1162, 1324, 816, 2486, 1430, 1330, 819, 984, 1422, 1921, 1640, 1032, 879, 1073, 1064, 934, 1059, 1458, 1040, 1967, 1949, 872, 1830, 1000, 810, 1700, 1350, 1150, 2009, 3672, 1560, 1488, 1057, 1609, 2559, 1440, 1876, 1208, 1846, 1590, 1809, 1614, 1596, 1388, 1100, 1499, 1425, 1749, 1779, 1388, 1282, 864, 1762, 1755, 1358, 1909, 2214, 2049, 1939, 1995, 848, 1390, 1737, 1611, 1336, 1436, 1012, 1176, 1724, 914, 2314, 1072, 1709, 936, 1338, 1669, 1482, 1414, 498, 1273, 1551, 1340, 1479, 1510, 1636, 1465, 1288, 1550, 1717, 1671, 1609, 1801, 2315, 976, 1285, 672, 641, 1638, 729, 1396, 936, 1778, 1646, 1625, 1664, 1491, 1210, 1650, 1403, 1960, 1838, 1600, 1368, 1304, 874, 1652, 630, 1092, 1360, 1092, 1092, 1092, 1092, 1224, 970, 2000]
from scipy.stats import boxcox
print(boxcox(data))
```

```
/home/swozny/untitled5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/morestats.py:901: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  llf -= N / 2.0 * np.log(np.sum((y - y_mean)**2. / N, axis=0))
/home/swozny/untitled5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py:2189: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  w = xb - ((xb - xc) * tmp2 - (xb - xa) * tmp1) / denom
/home/swozny/untitled5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py:1849: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  tmp1 = (x - w) * (fx - fv)
/home/swozny/untitled5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py:1850: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  tmp2 = (x - v) * (fx - fw)
/home/swozny/untitled5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py:1851: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  p = (x - v) * tmp2 - (x - w) * tmp1
(array([ 0.12241068,  0.12241068,  0.12241068, ...,  0.12241068,
        0.12241068,  0.12241068]), -8.16922204235409)
```

As you can see all data has been mapped to the same value by the transform: `0.12241068`

However if I just leave out one element everything works fine:

```
print(boxcox(data[:-1]))
```

```
(array([ 7.11124803,  6.83369809,  7.15089095, ...,  6.70114334,
        6.80570793,  6.59243   ]), -0.012390354600346196)
```

And this is true for any element I remove:

```
print(boxcox(data[:-2]+[data[-1]]))
```

```
(array([ 7.14427608,  6.86415735,  7.18429468, ...,  6.73041367,
        6.8359141 ,  7.28835118]), -0.011127011306744832)
```

Or add:

```
print(boxcox(data[:-2]+[data[-1]]))
```

```
(array([ 28.69866725,  25.85642313,  29.12759652, ...,  23.5995206 ,
    30.27105033,   0.77229995]), 0.30657228704911826)
```

Is there something wrong with my data or am I using the function wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!

My data is numerically unstable as soon as the last element is larger than `543.82`:

```
print(boxcox(data[:-1]+[543.83]))
```

The real issue here is that the underlying optimization algorithm used to find the optimal `lambda` parameter of the `boxcox` transform isn't aware of this issue and returns a small, albeit not very small `float` instead of just plain returning `0`.

I ended up checking if the returned `lambda` is negative:

```
def init_boxcox() -> Tuple[Callable, Callable]:
    from scipy.special import inv_boxcox as inverse
    from scipy.stats import boxcox as forward
    lambdas = dict()

    def myforward(data: pd.Series):
        transformed, lambdas[data.name] = forward(1 + data)
        if lambdas[data.name]<0:
            lambdas[data.name]=0
        transformed=np.log1p(data)
        return transformed

    def myinverse(data: pd.Series):
        if lambdas[data.name]==0:
            return np.expm1(data)
        else:
            transformed = inverse(data, lambdas[data.name])-1
        return transformed

    return myforward, myinverse
```

This is good enough for my case.